# Extracting / viewing the Value of a ScriptMethod

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm fairly new to powershell and am digging about,  learning as I go.

Specifically I would like to know how to view the code relating to an overridden method or added ScriptMethod.

The cmdlet: **Get-Service** returns an object which has a **ScriptMethod**  MemberType called **ToString**

```
PS> Get-Service | Get-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod 

TypeName: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

Name     MemberType   Definition               
----     ----------   ----------               
ToString ScriptMethod System.Object ToString();
```

I know you can use the **Add-Member** cmdlet to override the underlying .NET ToString() with something like:

```
$gps = Get-Process s* | Select-Object -First 3 | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name ToString -Value {$this.Name} -PassThru -Force
```

Note: **Get-Process** uses the default .NET ToString() but can be overridden with the **Add-Member** cmdlet.

But how can I extract the **-Value {*some_code*}** from an object which implements a **ScriptMethod** MemberType?

I have searched for an answer to this but to no avail.

Anyone know?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Script` property or `get_Script` method:

```powershell
(Get-Service | Select-Object -First 1).ToString | Get-Member -Force


TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSScriptMethod

Name                    MemberType   Definition
----                    ----------   ----------
...
get_Script              Method       scriptblock get_Script()
...
Script                  Property     scriptblock Script {get;}
...
```

Example:

```powershell
(Get-Service | Select-Object -First 1).ToString.Script
```

Result:

```powershell
$this.ServiceName
```

Comment: For this to work, an instance should be present or created beforehand. Below answer from @Mathias R. Jesses provides the definition straight away.

Answer (score 3):

You can also access it through the hidden `psobject` property:

```
$gps.psobject.Methods|?{$_.MemberType-eq'ScriptMethod'}|select -exp Script
```

Comment: This is interesting. I would have set this to the accepted answer also if I could have. I will investigate the hidden psobject some more. Thanks.